What's the best way to copy AL to AH, and/or AX to the upper half of EAX?
Say my EAX register is as follows:
0x00000012
If I then want to duplicate the AL byte to the rest of the register, resulting in...
0x12121212
...how should that be done? Is there an x86 instruction to do this, or is the best way just to use another register and shift?
Same goes for any other register of course (and 64-bit).

Are you allowed to clobber other registers like EDX/RDX?

Out of curiosity, what's the use case for this?

multiply by 0x01010101 is probably as good as anything.

@ErikEidt, I'm using REP to write a repeated byte to a section of memory, but I'd rather use STOSD with that byte extended to a doubleword for less repetitions.

@MartinBrown That seems to be what I'm looking for!

If you're on a modern CPU (at least Intel since Ivy Bridge, not sure about AMD), you'll have the ERMSB feature which makes rep stosb at least as efficient as rep stosq.  Enhanced REP MOVSB for memcpy .  (On most CPUs with ERMSB, rep stosd and rep stosq also benefit from it, but a few don't.)

If you care about efficiency for short or misaligned blocks, you'll want to broadcast it into an XMM or YMM register, e.g. with AVX2 vmovd + vpbroadcastb or AVX-512 vpbroadcastb ymm0, eax, and use SIMD loops.  e.g. glibc's memset implementation https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memset-vec-unaligned-erms.S.html or Agner Fog's string library https://www.agner.org/optimize/ and optimization guides.

It is difficult to imagine how the code sequence to replicate al across register will affect the timing of the over all operation, as that will be dominated by the memory transfer.
